# Custom scheme for redirect in electron

Tags: reactjs, electron

I have implement the checkout of Octobat Beanies (Payment with VAT) , and when my payment is succeed, the system redirect to an url.

I have try to create a custom scheme with setAsDefaultProtocolClient function but it doesn't work.

I have made my project with Electron and React Js.

Do you have any issue about making a custom scheme ?
Thanks in advance,

Louis

```
beanie.redirectToBeanie({
            items: [
                { price: price.productId, quantity: 1 } // For one-off charges only
            ],
            successUrl: `http://localhost://home`,
            cancelUrl: 'https://example.com/cancel',
            primaryColor: '#715b9e',
            billingAddressCollection: 'required'
        })
            .then(function (result) {
                if (result.error) {
                    // If `redirectToBeanie` fails due to a browser or network
                    // error, display the localized error message to your customer.
                }

            }).catch(function(error) {
            // If `redirectToBeanie` can't be triggered because of invalid parameters
            // or implementation, error, display a generic error message to your customer,
            // and report the error to the console for debugging purposes, or send it to Sentry
            // Sentry.log(error)
            console.log(error)
        })
```

Comment: "I have try to create a custom scheme with setAsDefaultProtocolClient function but it doesn't work." Can you elaborate?

Comment: I have try to implement  setAsDefaultProtocolClient with a string in parameter, but when octobat try to redirect, electron show an error like  : "Unable to find Electron app".